# How do i set my INT values from int32 to int64 using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question about pandas `to_numeric`. I'm trying to cast a Colum from a float to INT, however `df.info` is stating my Colum is being cast to a int32.

First question, I thought the default INT value using to_numeric is int64? [Source](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)

> to_numeric(arg, errors='raise', downcast=None) Convert
> argument to a numeric type.
>
> The default return dtype is float64 or int64 depending on the data
> supplied. Use the downcast parameter to obtain other dtypes.

Second Question, How do I change it from int32 to int 64 as a MPRN is more the ten numbers and I'm getting negative values in my Dataframe now.

> My code example

```
   import pandas as pd

  df['MPRN'] = pd.to_numeric(df['MPRN'], errors="coerce").fillna(0).astype(int).to_frame()

df.info()
```

> MPRN                                 387 non-null    int32

Comment: Try `df = df.astype({"MRN": np.dtype("int64")})`

Comment: Or `df['MPRN'] = pd.to_numeric(df['MPRN'], errors="coerce").fillna(0).astype('int64')`

Comment: Oh wow, that was easy! Thanks! i tired just int64 but it didn't work but putting them into a  string did the trick! Do you know why it works this way and not with just a int64?

Comment: Problem is with int types cannot have empty values like double types or string values and if it was already as int32, you then lose values as they took only partial value not whole. With strings you can convert to int64 as you dont lose those values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['MPRN'] = pd.to_numeric(df['MPRN'], errors="coerce").fillna(0).astype('int64')
```